# Runtime error 1004 Application defined or object defined error in vlookup using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Working within 2 worbook i.e (new vs old). I'm trying to use vlookup formula old vs new workbook to find out if the ID is missing.Below is the code use to run the macros.

```
Set OB1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FTO_New_BRNO)

    name1 = ActiveWorkbook.name
    sheet_name1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).name

    Set OB2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(FTO_Old_Brno)

   ' name2 = ActiveWorkbook.name
   ' sheet_name2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).name



    OB2.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Compare With New Brno Tracker"
    OB2.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Range("C3").Select
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],[" & name1 & "]" & sheet_name1 & "!C1,1,0)"
```

The above vlookup formula gives me a below error

```
Runtime Error 1004 - "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"
```

Comment: If the purpose is to find out if an ID is missing you expect your formula to return an error and then take action. However, by placing the VLOOKUP in the cell the error, once you insert the function correctly, will be produced in the worksheet where you can't take action. Try using VBA's `Find` method to look for the ID and then use the found range's `Row` property to retrieve the ID.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks for your help. I've made slight tweak in my code and posted my code in answer section.

Comment: @Variatus Thanks for your help. I've made slight tweak in my code and posted my code in answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I found out the solutions. There is slight tweak in macro code as shown in below updated code. Finally it worked.

Old code

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2],[" & name1 & "]" & sheet_name1 & "!C1,1,0)"
```

New code

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(C[-2],'[" & name1 & "]" & sheet_name1 & "'!C1,1,0)"
```

Comment: I don't see how that could work. I originally misread your formula and thought the `C1` was an A1-style reference to the cell C1, when in fact it was an R1C1 reference to entire column 1. Your amended formula tries to search the entire column C[-2] inside the entire column 1, and that is not how vlookup works. The sought for value should be a scalar.